# Buenas practicas sobre uso de Include dentro de un While?

Tags: php

Tengo una plantilla sobre caja para los productos, entonces estuve practicando en realizar un `include` de esa plantilla dentro de un `While` de la siguiente manera:

```
$stmt->bind_result($product);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    include 'template_box_product.php';
}
```

Entonces a esa plantilla ya le agrego las variables del `bind_result`:

```
<div class="item product">
    <div class="thumbnail image">
        <img src="default.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="heading">
            <h3><?php echo $product; ?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <p><label>$300</label><em class="item-price">$120,00</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto funciono sin problemas, pero es una buena practica realizarlo de esta manera, me refiero en temas de tiempo de ejecución, rendimiento, ¿Qué otros aspectos se deben evaluar para tomar decisiones?

O se debe emplear de la manera más habitual/común:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
echo '<div class="item product">
    <div class="thumbnail image">
        <img src="default.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="heading">
            <h3>'.$product.'</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <p><label>$300</label><em class="item-price">$120,00</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que la idea de tener el contenido en un archivo para luego incluirlo es tener el código mejor organizado y/o poder reutilizar código, lo cual es una buena práctica.

Una forma de asegurar la separación de contenidos sería poner un `return` al archivo `template_box_product.php` y recuperarlo luego en una variable **una sola vez**, usando luego esa variable. Así evitarás un include dentro de un bucle, lo cual no es una buena idea, porque al fin y al cabo es código repetitivo.

En cuanto a los valores dinámicos, puedes poner marcadores y organizar la salida con [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php).

Entonces, `template_box_product.php` quedaría así:

```
$html='
<div class="item product">
    <div class="thumbnail image">
        <img src="default.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="heading">
            <h3>%s</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
            <p><label>$300</label><em class="item-price">$120,00</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';

return $html;
```

Y, cuando quieras usarlo:

```
$html=include 'template_box_product.php';

$stmt->bind_result($product);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf($html,$producto); 
}
```

Lo que ocurrirá aquí es que el marcador `%s` que pusimos aquí: `<h3>%s</h3>` será sustituido por el valor de `$producto` en cada iteracción. Si necesitaras más valores, pones más marcadores y pasas los valores respectivos como parámetros. Aquí la `s` significa un marcador para un dato de tipo cadena (string), y hay otros tipos de marcadores según el tipo de dato, [como podrás ver en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php).

Comment: Tengo una duda, si yo tengo una `function` que me genera contenido `HTML` es sobre un diseño de `star rating` lo cual es el encargado lo siguiente `display_star_print($avg_print)` esto debo pasarlo también por medio de `printf` o ya directamente en la plantilla de retorno?